# Proof that $f(x)=0 \forall x \in [a,b]$

Tags: analysis, functions

**Lemma**:

If $f \in C([a,b])$ and $\int_a^b f(x) h(x) dx=0 \  \forall h \in C^2([a,b])$ with $h(a)=h(b)=0$ then $f(x)=0 \ \forall x \in [a,b]$.

**Proof of lemma**:

Suppose that there is a $x_0 \in (a,b)$ such that $f(x_0) \neq 0$, for example without loss of generality we suppose that $f(x_0)>0$.
Because of continuity there is an interval $[x_1, x_2] \subset (a,b)$ such that $x_0 \in (x_1, x_2)$ and $f(x)>0 \ \forall x \in (x_1, x_2)$.

We define the function $g(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
(x_2-x)^3 (x-x_1)^3 & , x \in (x_1, x_2)\\ \\
0 & ,  x \in [a,b] \setminus{(x_1,x_2)} 
\end{matrix}\right.$.

Then $g \in C^2([a,b])$ and $g(a)=g(b)=0$. From the hypothesis we have:

$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx=0$$

But $\int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx= \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)g(x) dx>0$, contradiction.

First of all, why do we say that there is an interval $[x_1, x_2] \subset (a,b)$ such that $x_0 \in (x_1, x_2)$ and $f(x)>0 \forall x \in (x_1, x_2)$? Why don't we pick the closed interval $[x_1, x_2]$ ?

Also why does it hold that $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx= \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x) g(x) dx$?

Furthermore, the prof told us that we couldn't take the function

$g(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
(x_2-x)^2 (x-x_1)^2 & , x \in (x_1, x_2)\\ \\
0 & ,  x \in [a,b] \setminus{(x_1,x_2)} 
\end{matrix}\right.$

but the powers both of $(x_2-x), (x-x_1)$ have to be greater or equal to $3$. Why is it like that?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

1. Just a mater of taste.
2. Because $g(x)$, and therefore $f(x)g(x)$, is zero outside $(x_1,x_2)$.
3. Because the function must be *twice* continuously differentiable.

Comment: If we would pick the function $g(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
(x_2-x)^2 (x-x_1)^2 &, x \in (x_1,x_2) \\ 
0, & x \in [a,b] \setminus(x_1,x_2)
\end{matrix}\right.$

then we would have $g''(x)=-(x-x_1)^2+2(x_2-x)^2$ and $\lim_{x \to x_1} g''(x)=2(x_2-x_1)^2 \neq 0$, right?
$$$$

Is this the reason why we couldn't take this $g$ ? Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: @evinda That's right. $g''(x_1)$ and $g''(x_2)$ are not defined, since on one side it goes towards $2(x_2-x_1)^2$, and on the other side it's constantly $0$. This is not continuous.

Comment: Nice :) And for the point 1 we could also pick the closed interval, right?

Comment: @evinda yes, but it has to be an _interval_, and not just a single number, and it has to be strictly inside $(a,b)$. Saying that $x_0\in(x_1,x_2)\subseteq [x_1,x_2]\subseteq (a,b)$ fixes that. It's also the fact the set of $x$ for which $f(x)>0$ _must_ be open (this is a consequence of continuity). So using an open interval from the start saves you some work. So using a closed interval is possible, but using an open interval saves you some additional explaining.